# Git log missing a commit - Visual Studio showing it

Tags: git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree, missing-data, sourcetree

A co-worker of mine used Visual Studio to commit and push a change to a branch that we are both working on,  but the commit does not show up when I do `git log -5 -p <filename>`. The subsequent commits seem to have ignored the change completely, and unfortunately we noticed this long after the fact. Our quick fix was to push a new commit with the same changes.

To make things more confusing, the commit **does** show up in Visual Studio when I right click the file and choose "View History". It also shows up in Atlassian Source Tree. All commits and investigation was done on the same branch. I can view the specific commit if I do `git log <commit>`, so I know it's not missing completely. I also made sure to pull any changes before committing.

Does anyone understand what may have happened here? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: You only talk about committing, presumably you also mean that your co-worker pushed that commit to a remote repository, that you're also pulling from?

Comment: Just to check !
You can see the commit if you do a simple 'git log'?
Are you sure that <filename> is correct (the path, name, extension, etc)?
Did you made a git pull? Are you in the same branch?

Comment: Yes to all, thank you guys. I just made some edits to clarify.